# How do i stop elements from moving when resizing the browser?

Tags: html, css, browser, resize, wrapper

When i resize my browser my div tags resize themselves. I've added min-width: which i thought would stop it but it does not.

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="adleft"></div>
<div id="adright"></div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper{ 
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#adleft {
  height: 500px;
  min-width: 48%;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}
#adright {
  height: 500px;
  min-width: 48%;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: % based widths will always be % of the parent. You need to fix with `px` or another unit if you want to define specific widths or min/max-widths.

Comment: `min-width` is the SMALLEST you want them to go, but since all of your widths are relative, they're GOING to resize themselves when the containers (e.g. your browser window) change.

Comment: Instead of using percentages on your min-width, use pixels

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8yycvqas/   is this what you were expecting to do?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are applying a `min-width` as a `%` not in `px`.

Using a `%` means that when the browser window shrinks 48% becomes less and less pixels. If you define the `min-width` in pixels it will stop shrinking when it hits the minimum number of pixels you declare.

Comment: Thank you :) I've done that but now when i move the browser they over lap each other. What i want to do is this :http://i58.tinypic.com/zv6hdl.png                                                      So when the browser is adjusted in size in anyway it stays exactly where it is.

Comment: what is the min-with in pixels that you want?

Comment: set width:48% and then set min-width:100px for example

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="ad">
    <div id="adleft"></div>
    <div id="adright"></div>
</div>
```

Include this in your Css:

```
#ad
{
    Display: table;
    Margin-left: auto;
    Margin-right: auto;

}
#adleft 
{
    height: 500px;
    min-width: 48%;
    background-color: red;
    Margin-right:20px;
}
#adright
{
    height: 500px;
    min-width: 48%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Post your solution as an answer

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me : 
Html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="adleft"></div>
<div id="adright"></div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper{ 
max-width: 960px;
min-width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 30px;
}

#adleft {
height: 500px;
width: 48%;
background-color: red;
float: left;
}
#adright {
height: 500px;
width: 48%;
background-color: red;
float: right;

}
```